# How to get a role in discord.py and if the role is not there create the role

Tags: python, discord.py

I was wondering if anyone knows how to get a role and if the role does not exsit in the server it then creates the role this is the code so far.

```
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
```

I now just need to know how to see if the role is there and if not the role gets created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`utils.get` can return `None` if it doesn't find anything, you can check for that with an if statement:

```py
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, named="Muted")

if role is None:
    # Doesn't exist, create the role here
    role = await ctx.guild.create_role(...)
```

#### Reference:

- [`Guild.create_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_role)